# Implementing interface correct terminology

Tags: c#, java, c++, oop

If I have a method that has as argument a **Base class** type I can pass it every object of a class that has extended that base class because a ***derived class is also a base class***.

So if I have a method that has as argument an **Interface** type I can pass it every object of a class that has implemented that interface because ***that class is also an interface*** or all the interfaces it can implement.

Is that the correct terminology to use with the interface?

Thanks.

Comment: a class is not an interface,it *implements* an interface

Comment: @Felice: Inheritance means "Is a" So you could say both.

Comment: @schoetbi, to my mind, implimenting an interface is **not** inheritance.

Comment: @schoetbi: The key part is that a class which implements an interface is not necessarily an interface itself which can be implemented by a third class. Inheritance is not the same as implementation.

Comment: This is probably a matter of opinion. I wouldn't say that a class is an (typeof)interface but rather because it implements interface. So when a parameter requires IEntity it means it takes any class that "Implements" IEntity rather then "is" IEntity. But I guess this is all semantics.

Comment: @George: I agree that nobody says that but if the implementation of an interface does not change the semantics of the inferface the Liskov Substitution Principle apply (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) therefore I think it is valid to say its an interitance becaus it is indeed a "Is A" Relationship. But everybody will understand what he means no matter if he says inheritance or implements. More common is "implements" I agree.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct terminology would not be

***that class is also an interface***

but

***that class can behave exactly as the interface promises***

instead.

With bases classes, it is like "I can work with any hard worker." With interfaces, it is like "I can work with anything that works hard."

Comment: yes this is quite correct language used. "that class behave exactly as interface promises."

Comment: I would not agree with using the word "behave". It's ok for two implementations of the same interface to behave differently. The binding terminology is that an implementation of an interface is compatible with a certain communication protocol.

Answer (score 4):

`that class is also an interface` I don't agree with this line. That class is not an interface, that class just have implemented that interface. In my opinion this statement `that class is also an interface` would be wrong

Answer (score 1):

More precise formulations would be "any *instance of* a class `D` that derives from a base class `B` is also an *instance of* `B`", and "any *instance of* a class `D` that implements an interface `I` may also be *referenced* through `I`". This way of phrasing it makes a clear distinction between class, interface, and instance.

Answer (score 0):

> that class is also an interface

I wouldn't express it that way (mainly because a class **is not** an interface). I'd express it like that:

- .. that class provides the API of the interface ..
- .. that class provides the behavior defined by the interface
- .. that class implements the interface ..